# Injecting HTML at specific location using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I've been asked to inject a bunch of HTML into a specific point in a HTML document, and have been looking at using HTMLAgilityPack to do so.
The recomended way to do this, as far as I can tell, is to parse using nodes and replace/delete the relevant nodes.

This is my code so far

```
//Load original HTML
var originalHtml = new HtmlDocument();
originalHtml.Load(@"C:\Temp\test.html");

//Load inject HTML
var inject = new HtmlDocument();
inject.Load(@"C:\Temp\Temp\inject.html");
var injectNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(inject.Text);

//Get all HTML nodes to inject/delete
var nodesToDelete = originalHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@style='page-break-after:avoid']");
var countToDelete = nodesToDelete.Count();

//loop through stuff to remove
int count = 0;
foreach (var nodeToDelete in nodesToDelete)
{
    count++;
    if (count == 1)
    {
        //replace with inject HTML
        nodeToDelete.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(injectNode, nodeToDelete);
    }
    else if (count <= countToDelete)
    {
        //remove, as HTML already injected
        nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
    }
}
```

What I'm finding, is that the original HTML is not correctly updated, it appears as though it only injects the parent level node, which is a simple  and none of the child nodes.

Any help??

Thanks,

Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't work out how to do this using HTMLAgilityPack, probably more due to my lack of understanding of nodes more than anything else, but I did find an easy fix using AngleSharp.

```
//Load original HTML into document
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var htmlDocument = parser.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\test.html"));

//Load inject HTML as raw text
var injectHtml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\inject.html")

//Get all HTML elements to inject/delete
var elements = htmlDocument.All.Where(e => e.Attributes.Any(a => a.Name == "style" && a.Value == "page-break-after:avoid"));

//loop through stuff to remove
int count = 1;
foreach (var element  in elements)
{
    if (count == 1)
    {
        //replace with inject HTML
        element.OuterHtml = injectHtml;
    }
    else
    {
        //remove, as HTML already injected
        element.Remove();
    }
    count++;
}


//Re-write updated file
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\test_updated.html", string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}","<html>",htmlDocument.Head.OuterHtml,htmlDocument.Body.OuterHtml,"</html>"));
```